# Automatically table created in NancyFx

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

When I insert,select,update or delete rows in a table in an existing database,Nancy create a table with Model Class Name and Model attributes.
How can I stop this?

Comment: Nancy is a web framework that doesn't do data access. Show your relevant Entity Framework code.

Comment: 'using System.Data.Entity;
using MobileSales.Models;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;


namespace MobileSales
{
    public class SalesContext : DbContext
    {
        public SalesContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        //public DbSet<USER> USER { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TEMPLATE_TEST> TEMPLATE { get; set; }

        //public DbSet<TEMP> TEMPLATE { get; set; }'

Comment: Yeah please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Just your DbContext isn't going to cut it.